# Use a service to monitor when other activites/applications start or end

Tags: android, service, android-activity, monitor, notify

Is it possible to make a service running in backgroud to be notified when an arbritary activity/application is started and ended by a user? I want to use it to log how often and for how long different applications are used in Android.

Comment: Do you want to track usages of your own application, or other applications such as Facebook, Twitter etc?

Comment: In this case you might need a receiver not a Service

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `ActivityManager.getRunningTasks()`.  Unfortunately you would need to be running continuously to see tasks starting and stopping.  I'm not aware of any event you can listen for.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in question & answer posted bellow:

> There is no solution other than periodically read a list of processes and detecting foreground process. You need a service for this. Unfortunately, Android does not provide means such as broadcast events for foreground process change.

[App to monitor other apps on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416610/app-to-monitor-other-apps-on-android) and [the reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20543148/3444151) which contains interesting and usefull suggestion and some sample code.