# How to create a Service which continuously monitors app usage information?

Tags: android, service, usage-statistics

**Problem at Hand**:
I have to create a `Service` which runs continuously. This service monitors 5 apps say 5 android games installed on your phone. This service needs to get the information of:
 1. How many times is the game opened and run? 
 2. For how much time each game has run.

for example: Say If I have this service installed in my app. And I let it run for a month. I need information of this kind on the screen of the app:

**Game**     **Number of times the game is run**     **Duration of Game play**

Game 1                     20 times played for                         15 hours in total

Game 2                     16 times played for                       25 hours in total

..

..

Game 5                   10 times played for                       12 hours in total

**Possible Approach**:
When an application loads it comes in the memory. Noting the system clocks time while the application starts. And when the application ends or is put in the background noting the time again.

So say if an application is brought to memory at 9:00 pm and exits to background at 9:30 pm that gives us a gameplay time of 30 mins. Next time the application is played the duration will be added to 30 from the previous play stored in some sort of variable and so on. 
Each time an application is brought into the memory the counter of it being played should increase by one. Hence giving us the number of times an application is played.

**Coding:**
I have no idea about `Service` in Android as I have never really worked on them. Any tutorials related to my problem at hand will be very helpful.
Secondly, if there is another way in which this could be done. I would like to know that as well. I could really use some code snippet for me to start this project.

Comment: This is exactly something that Google Analytics does. If you need it for analytics, you should just use GA, instead of reinventing your own version.

Comment: Are those 5 apps and games your own apps? Or are they any other apps the user has installed?

Comment: @AdnanMulla Other apps the user has installed.

Comment: @D'yer Mak'er . Not possible dude. If the app data you want to monitor is not your developed app. You cannot do anything with their data if they have not made it public.

Comment: @Javanator: Very much possible if we monitor the process names. Once the particular process is in the foreground. You could check the system time and the time when it goes to the background. The time difference will be the duration of the game play.

Comment: will appreciate if you can share some links supporting that or post your answer if you solved it..

Comment: @D'yerMak'er i wanan know till what hv u coded ? so that may help me to code further? any which application is to be monitered that is specified by user?

Comment: @D'yerMak'er Post your own answer if none of the given answer helped you and accept that itself or accept the most helpful one with your comments. So that other visitors can get the help out of it. Your bounty time is over.

Comment: @Javanator: I apologize for the inconvenience. I have been offline for more than 10 days. Awarding the bounty skipped my mind. I will go through the answers and accept the one which is the closest. also i will post the code currently i worked with for the other users so that they can benefit from the same.

Comment: @D'yerMak'er  can you post the code, I am stuck with the same problem

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As you wrote that the task is about monitoring 3-rd party applications, *there is no solution other than periodically read a list of processes and detecting foreground process*. You need a service for this. Unfortunately, Android does not provide means such as broadcast events for foreground process change.

The task requires a lot of code in fact, at least much more than an ordinary answer could comprise. I'm posting a part of it here, but you should address many nuances left behind the scenes, such as synchronization and persisting information between launches. This is just a skeleton.

First, lets code an application object, which is a good place to register all instance related stuff.

**MonitorApp**

```
public class MonitorApp extends Application
{
  // actual store of statistics
  private final ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> processList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();

  // fast-access index by package name (used for lookup)
  private ArrayList<String> packages = new ArrayList<String>();

  public ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> getProcessList()
  {
    return processList;
  }

  public ArrayList<String> getPackages()
  {
    return packages;
  }

  // TODO: you need to save and load the instance data
  // TODO: you need to address synchronization issues
}
```

Then lets draft an activity.

**MonitorActivity**

```
import static ProcessList.COLUMN_PROCESS_NAME;
import static ProcessList.COLUMN_PROCESS_PROP;
import static ProcessList.COLUMN_PROCESS_COUNT;
import static ProcessList.COLUMN_PROCESS_TIME;

public class MonitorActivity extends Activity implements MonitorService.ServiceCallback
{
  private ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> processList;
  private MonitorService backgroundService;
  private MyCustomAdapter adapter = null;
  private ListView listView = null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); // TODO: provide your layout
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.id_process_listview);
    createAdapter();

    this.bindService(
      new Intent(this, MonitorService.class),
      serviceConnection,
      Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
  }

  private void createAdapter()
  {
    processList = ((MonitorApp)getApplication()).getProcessList();
    adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, processList, R.layout.complex_list_item,
    new String[]
    {
      COLUMN_PROCESS_NAME,
      COLUMN_PROCESS_PROP, // TODO: you may calculate and pre-fill this field
                           // from COLUMN_PROCESS_COUNT and COLUMN_PROCESS_TIME
                           // so eliminating the need to use the custom adapter
    },
    new int[]
    {
      android.R.id.text1,
      android.R.id.text2
    });

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
  }

  // callback method invoked by the service when foreground process changed
  @Override
  public void sendResults(int resultCode, Bundle b)
  {
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }

  private class MyCustomAdapter extends SimpleAdapter
  {
    MyCustomAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to)
    {
      super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
      View result = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

      // TODO: customize process statistics display
      int count = (Integer)(processList.get(position).get(COLUMN_PROCESS_COUNT));
      int seconds = (Integer)(processList.get(position).get(COLUMN_PROCESS_TIME));

      return result;
    }
  }

  private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection()
  {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service)
    {
      LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder)service;
      backgroundService = binder.getService();
      backgroundService.setCallback(MonitorActivity.this);
      backgroundService.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className)
    {
      backgroundService = null;
    }
  };

  @Override
  public void onResume()
  {
    super.onResume();
    if(backgroundService != null)
    {
      backgroundService.setCallback(this);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause()
  {
    super.onPause();
    if(backgroundService != null)
    {
      backgroundService.setCallback(null);
    }
  }

}
```

The activity launches a background worker service, which does actually monitor processes. You could possibly move the service registration from the activity into the application instance. The service itself is something like this:

**MonitorService**

```
public class MonitorService extends Service
{
  private boolean initialized = false;
  private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
  private ServiceCallback callback = null;
  private Timer timer = null;
  private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
  private String foreground = null;
  private ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> processList;
  private ArrayList<String> packages;
  private Date split = null;

  public static int SERVICE_PERIOD = 5000; // TODO: customize (this is for scan every 5 seconds)

  private final ProcessList pl = new ProcessList(this)
  {
    @Override
    protected boolean isFilteredByName(String pack)
    {
      // TODO: filter processes by names, return true to skip the process
      // always return false (by default) to monitor all processes
      return false;
    }

  };

  public interface ServiceCallback
  {
    void sendResults(int resultCode, Bundle b);
  }

  public class LocalBinder extends Binder
  {
    MonitorService getService()
    {
      // Return this instance of the service so clients can call public methods
      return MonitorService.this;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate()
  {
    super.onCreate();
    initialized = true;
    processList = ((MonitorApp)getApplication()).getProcessList();
    packages = ((MonitorApp)getApplication()).getPackages();
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
  {
    if(initialized)
    {
      return mBinder;
    }
    return null;
  }

  public void setCallback(ServiceCallback callback)
  {
    this.callback = callback;
  }

  private boolean addToStatistics(String target)
  {
    boolean changed = false;
    Date now = new Date();
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(target))
    {
      if(!target.equals(foreground))
      {
        int i;
        if(foreground != null && split != null)
        {
          // TODO: calculate time difference from current moment
          // to the moment when previous foreground process was activated
          i = packages.indexOf(foreground);
          long delta = (now.getTime() - split.getTime()) / 1000;
          Long time = (Long)processList.get(i).get(COLUMN_PROCESS_TIME);
          if(time != null)
          { 
            // TODO: add the delta to statistics of 'foreground' 
            time += delta;
          }
          else
          {
            time = new Long(delta);
          }
          processList.get(i).put(COLUMN_PROCESS_TIME, time);
        }

        // update count of process activation for new 'target'
        i = packages.indexOf(target);
        Integer count = (Integer)processList.get(i).get(COLUMN_PROCESS_COUNT);
        if(count != null) count++;
        else
        {
          count = new Integer(1);
        }
        processList.get(i).put(COLUMN_PROCESS_COUNT, count);

        foreground = target;
        split = now;
        changed = true;
      }
    }
    return changed; 
  }


  public void start()
  {
    if(timer == null)
    {
      timer = new Timer();
      timer.schedule(new MonitoringTimerTask(), 500, SERVICE_PERIOD);
    }

    // TODO: startForeground(srvcid, createNotification(null));
  }

  public void stop()
  {
    timer.cancel();
    timer.purge();
    timer = null;
  }

  private class MonitoringTimerTask extends TimerTask
  {
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
      fillProcessList();

      ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)MonitorService.this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
      List<RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
      String current = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();

      // check if current process changed
      if(addToStatistics(current) && callback != null)
      {
        final Bundle b = new Bundle();
        // TODO: pass necessary info to UI via bundle
        mHandler.post(new Runnable()
        {
          public void run()
          {
            callback.sendResults(1, b);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }

  private void fillProcessList()
  {
    pl.fillProcessList(processList, packages);
  }

}
```

The service utilizes a helper class for building process lists.

**ProcessList**

```
public abstract class ProcessList
{
  // process package name
  public static final String COLUMN_PROCESS_NAME = "process";

  // TODO: arbitrary property (can be user-fiendly name)
  public static final String COLUMN_PROCESS_PROP = "property";

  // number of times a process has been activated
  public static final String COLUMN_PROCESS_COUNT = "count";

  // number of seconds a process was in foreground
  public static final String COLUMN_PROCESS_TIME = "time";

  private ContextWrapper context;

  ProcessList(ContextWrapper context)
  {
    this.context = context;
  }

  protected abstract boolean isFilteredByName(String pack);

  public void fillProcessList(ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> processList, ArrayList<String> packages)
  {
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfo = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

    HashMap<String, Object> hm;
    final PackageManager pm = context.getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();

    for(int i = 0; i < procInfo.size(); i++)
    {
      String process = procInfo.get(i).processName;
      String packageList = Arrays.toString(procInfo.get(i).pkgList);
      if(!packageList.contains(process))
      {
        process = procInfo.get(i).pkgList[0];
      }

      if(!packages.contains(process) && !isFilteredByName(process))
      {
        ApplicationInfo ai;
        String applicationName = "";

        for(int k = 0; k < procInfo.get(i).pkgList.length; k++)
        {
          String thisPackage = procInfo.get(i).pkgList[k];
          try
          {
            ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(thisPackage, 0);
          }
          catch(final NameNotFoundException e)
          {
            ai = null;
          }
          if(k > 0) applicationName += " / ";
          applicationName += (String)(ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");
        }

        packages.add(process);
        hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        hm.put(COLUMN_PROCESS_NAME, process);
        hm.put(COLUMN_PROCESS_PROP, applicationName);
        processList.add(hm);
      }
    }

    // optional sorting
    Comparator<HashMap<String, Object>> comparator = new Comparator<HashMap<String, Object>>()
    {
      public int compare(HashMap<String, Object> object1, HashMap<String, Object> object2) 
      {       
        return ((String)object1.get(COLUMN_PROCESS_NAME)).compareToIgnoreCase((String)object2.get(COLUMN_PROCESS_NAME));
      }
    };
    Collections.sort(processList, comparator);

    packages.clear();
    for(HashMap<String, Object> e : processList)
    {
      packages.add((String)e.get(COLUMN_PROCESS_NAME));
    }
  }

}
```

Finally, the manifest.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.yourpackage"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MonitorActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".MonitorService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

As you may see, it's already a lot of code. It's partially extracted from a working application, but I made fast changes for your needs, so there may be typos, all imports are skipped, etc. Nevertheless, I hope this helps a bit.

**ADDENDUM: Lollipop+**

Beware: the latest Android versions broke the abovementioned approach. Here is what the official documentation says about [getRunningTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses()) method and others:

> As of LOLLIPOP, this method is no longer available to third party applications: the introduction of document-centric recents means it can leak person information to the caller. For backwards compatibility, it will still retu rn a small subset of its data: at least the caller's own tasks, and possibly some other tasks such as home that are known to not be sensitive.

I think this is an overkill and could be done in much more selective and convenient way. Not to mention that this seems too theatrical considering many built-in features from Google with privacy concerns. Anyway, we can do nothing with this.

The only workaround is to implement Android accessibility service (more info [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/services.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html)) and intercept all actions with applications gaining and losing focus from there. The user should enable the service manually! Your application should somehow direct the user to do so.

Comment: @Stan: My sincere apologies for not accepting the answer earlier. I have been away. I should have awarded the bounty to this answer which helps a lot in making clear some things I was facing at that point of time. I will post some code later to show how I actually ended up doing this task. Thank you for your response. It is much appreciated.

Comment: I have java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.monitoring/com.app.monitoring.MonitorActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.app.monitoring.MonitorApp error. Why?

Comment: @RiefSapthana, did you mention your MonitorApp in the app manifest as `application`'s `android:name` attribute? If this does not help, please consider posting a separate question with more codes and environment data.

Answer (score 10):

My Thoughts,

1. Develop application that makes some of their data public to other process to access them.

   Google "How to use **content providers**".

   Each of your application will need to keep record of all the activity they performed. This data will be public to be accessed.
2. **You dont need to run a service all the time** for this then. Whenever your monitoring app gets opened. It just need to fetch that data from all the applications you want and display them accordingly.
3. For a case you want to submit that data on server periodically in background. **Then you need a service**. 
   But still you **dont need to run it forever**. 
   Do something like this.

   i) From service fetch data and upload to server.

   ii) Stop service and schedule an alarm after some time T1 to start your own service again to do step 1 again.

   iii) T1 depends on requirement. How refresh data you want on server.

I can even tell you code pieces pointer if you want for how to implement what i said above.
But i suggest you to find that on google and do it yourself first. Post another specific question on StackOverflow if you face any difficulty in that.

Hope this helps. :)

Edit:

Firstly. Its only you who has to code in the end. Take pointer and help from here. Dont expect full code. Check more details below.

A)

You need to make your apps as Content Provider. Check the link below. and follow the examples in it. You will end up in a app whose data will be available to others. Its easy go ahead.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

All your games app needs to make data public to be accessed.
Now once you are done with this.

Now you just need to access all the data in your monitoring app and display it.

B)

As i said if you want to do this via service. 
You dont need to run it forever. Just start service for once, loads the data from content provider and do whatever you want to do. Set an alarm to invoke the service at a later stage to re do the same operation.

I assume if every 10 min your service can fetch data from content provider(Your games app that you want to monitor). It will be like following.

```
public class MonitoringService extends Service {

    private static final String ACTION_FETCH = "action_fetch";
    private static final int REPEAT_DATALOAD_INTERVAL_MS = 10 * 60 * 1000; // 10 Min

    private static PendingIntent makeSelfPendingIntent(Context context) {
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getService(
                           context, 0, makeSelfIntent(context), 0);
        return intent;
    }

    private static Intent makeSelfIntent(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MonitoringService.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_FETCH);
        return intent;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(ACTION_FETCH)) {
                loadDataFromContentProviderDoWhateverYouWantThen();
                setAlarmToRedoLoad();
                stopSelf();

            }
        }
        return Super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private void setAlarmToRedoLoad() {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) 
                                     getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                     System.currentTimeMillis() + REPEAT_DATALOAD_INTERVAL_MS,
                     makeSelfPendingIntent(getApplicationContext()));
    }

    private void loadDataFromContentProviderDoWhateverYouWantThen(){
        check this link how to load data from content provider.
        as your games app are content providers. It should be loaded easily.
        then do whatever you want display, upload anything

        http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html
    }

    // Call this method from onCreate of your monitoring app
    public static void start(Context context) {
        Intent intent = makeSelfIntent(context);
        context.startService(intent);
    }

}
```

C) make sure you allow user of your monitoring app to stop this service anytime. Dont forget to cancel alarm in that case.  so it dont run in background forever.

D) You can also make things broadcast based. Whenever your games app saves data they should broadcast this event and let your service gets invoked after listening that broadcast. loads it then only.

E) As Phill also stated you can go for Google Analytics as well.

How you want to actually do this is now depends on your requirement

Hope this helps. Try it out and let me know what more issue you are facing

Comment: I would greatly appreciate the some code please. As this is urgent for me.And all my tries have gone in vein.

Answer (score 1):

Use this example code it is for checking if the browser is running

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for(int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++){
        if(procInfos.get(i).processName.equals("com.android.browser")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Browser is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

To create a service you have to create a class that extends from Service base class and implement the function in an infinite loop such as `while(true)` in the `onStartCommand()` function. don't forget to add your service in the manifest file between `<service></service>` tags , a good tutorial is on http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Answer (score 1):

To get the current running application you can use:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
String packageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
```

You can check this periodically from your running service. You will need also define a required permission in your manifest: `android.permission.GET_TASKS`

Comment: @Stan I used your example, however there is one stumbling block please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771927/how-to-detect-the-total-time-spent-on-each-application-uptime-duration

Answer (score 0):

Following solutions based on the assumption that you own all five apps you are trying to monitor. If it other wise i will provide you another solution.

Let's breakdown the problem now.

1. Information service about app running or not.
2. Designing service
3. storing data

You should use `Intent` to broadcast messages about your app running or not. Use activity `onPause` and `onResume` to broadcast messages.

Now call this function from onPause and onResume,

```
   public void broadcastMessage(String method_name){
        Intent intent=new Intent("com.service.myservice");
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("app_name", this.getApplicationInfo().packageName);
        bundle.putLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis());
            //just to keep track if it is on pause or in on resume
        bundle.putString("method", method_name);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        this.startService(intent);
    }
```

and you can call this like the following way

```
public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        broadcastMessage(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName());
    }
```

Or

```
public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        broadcastMessage("onPause");
    }
```

So why onPause and onResume because gamer is playing game only between these functions calls.

**Designing Service**

Use `IntentService` and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15524280/service-vs-intent-service) if you wanna know why.

```
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
        String app_name=bundle.getString("app_name");
        long time=bundle.getLong("time");
        //then do whatever you wanna do with this data

    }
```

**Storing**

`ContentProvider` is a good option for storing data, and it is also very powerful; integrate and scale well on Android, but in this case seems like you only want to store some very simple information and as such you can also pick something very simple.

Code bellow uses `SharedPreferences`.

```
 protected void storeData(String app_name, long time) {
        if ((app_name==null)||(time<=0)) return;
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
              //concatenating app name just to make key unique
        long start_time=sharedPreferences.getLong(app_name+"_start_time", -1);
        if (start_time==-1){
            //start time is empty means this is my start time
            // and user just started the app
            editor.putLong(app_name+"_start_time", time);
            editor.putLong(app_name+"_counter", sharedPreferences.getLong(app_name+"_counter", 0)+1);
        }else{
            //user is now closing the app. 
            long time_played=time-start_time;
            long total_time=sharedPreferences.getLong(app_name+"_total_time", 0);
            total_time=total_time+time_played;
            //saving total time
            editor.putLong(app_name+"_total_time", time);
            //removing start time for next pass
            editor.remove(app_name+"_start_time");
        }
        editor.commit();
    }
    public long getTotalTimeUserSpent(String app_name){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        return sharedPreferences.getLong(app_name+"_total_time", 0);
    }
    public long numberOfTimeUserPlayed(String app_name){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        return sharedPreferences.getLong(app_name+"_counter", 0);
    }
```

just call these method from `onHandleIntent` .

Last piece of puzzle would be distribution. You can distribute this on a separate app or part of these five apps. Separate apps is the easiest route to take. But if you choose to use this as a part of all five of these apps, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204492/android-shared-service) discussion.

Answer (score -4):

Installing [Covenant Eyes](http://www.covenanteyes.com/) on your Android device will monitor all Internet traffic on the phone’s pre-installed browser and report additional apps that are being used onto the device.