# Android intent when other app is resumed

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

Can I receive an intent with a receiver when another app is resumed? I want to trigger something when another app is started or resumed.

Markus

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447912/android-detecting-application-launch-from-home-or-history is not it

Comment: Refer: http://androidexample.com/Check_Current_Running_Activity_%7C_Task_%7C_Application_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=111&aaid=133

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416610/app-to-monitor-other-apps-on-android if you are creating both apps then you can send a broadcast in onresume of an app